# wcf+desktop app or website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I am developing a school management system and I am struggling whether I should develop for [desktop app + wcf] or web app(website). Which one is going to be the best for the given scenario?

The main goals for the “Integrated Web-Based School Management and Quality Audits Software Project for Secondary Schools are outlined below. In addition, specific objectives within each of the goals have been provided.

- Goal 1: To facilitate automated data entries in secondary schools

  - Objective 1:1- To provide internet facilities and computer systems for secondary schools to further facilitate entries of student information into an integrated school management system.
  - Objective 1:2- To provide teachers with the possibility to enter continuous assessment data into the computer systems for each student.
  - Objective 1:3- To provide teachers with the possibility to enter end of term results for each student.
  - Objective 1:4:- To provide teachers with the possibility to enter students’ conduct at end of term for each student
  - Objective 1:5:- To provide the administration office with the possibility to register new students into the system
  - Objective 1:6:- To provide finance/fees office with the possibility to enter fees information for each student
  - Objective 1:7:- To provide parents with the possibility to access their children’s information online and provide feedback when needed or requested to do so
- Goal 2:- To generate a portfolio of student information in respect of each student. A unique student identification will be used to access each student’s portfolio. The following are the main components of the portfolio.

  - Objective 2:1:- One of the components of the students’ portfolio page will be the Result Slip of the immediate last examination term. This will display all subjects taken by the student, continuous assessment results, examination results, grades and positions obtained in each subject, overall student position, student’s conduct and recommendation information. This report will automatically be gathered from the various inputs made from the individual teachers and staff
  - Objective 2:2:- Up to date historical record of Fees Information. This is vital information that will be available on each student portal. All fees due and all payments made that are entered by the fees/finance staff will be gathered by this component of the portfolio. Parents will be able to see this as well and provide feedback on any observed discrepancies.
  - Objective 2:3:- Attendance and Conduct report. This component of the portfolio is intended to give an account of the student’s attendance records and information on conduct as provided by the school authorities. If the information demands parent’s attention and feedback, this will be indicated here, and parents will be able to enter relevant feedback as requested.
  - Objective 2:4:- Completed and Pending Assignments Module. This component of the student’s portfolio will list all assignments completed by the student in the current term and will list uncompleted ones as well.
- Goal 3:- To generate aggregated data for the management of the school. This will enable the school management have a high-level overview of student population, performance statistics for all the modules in the various classes, aggregated data on fees paid and fees pending, etc. There will hyperlinks or select options from which authorized staff will click or select from, in order to reach the requested aggregated data. Main components of the management page are listed below,

  - Objective 3:1:- One of the components of the staff portfolio page will be the Population Statistics. This will indicate total number of students, which is expandable to also list number of males and number of females. This can further be expanded to list female and male students in the various classes
  - Objective 3:2:- Performance Overview is another component of the staff portfolio. This will provide a high level overview of students’ performance. Per each class and for each subject, this module will list the number of Grade A students, Grade B students and so on and so forth. This links can be further expanded to view the number of males and females who obtained the various grades in the various classes. This module will also compare grades obtained in one subject with another to give an overview of modules that students do very well with those that they do not, to help management take quick action to rectify any anomalies
  - Objective 3:3:- Fees Overview is another component of the staff portfolio. This will provide fees information in the form of total fees paid within a specific period (Selectable from term, year, previous year(s), all years until current term, etc.). This information can be further expanded to show fees owed per class, payments overdue and allow the fees office to generate generic reminder messages in the form of email or text messages to parents of students who are overdue.

Comment: When you say "[desktop app + wcf] vs web app(website)" are you talking about WCF as a self-hosted app vs WCF as an IIS hosted app, or do you mean a "web app" as in ASP.NET serving HTML pages?

Comment: i mean web app as in ASP.NET and desktop application and wcf (say web services )as the bridge to transfer the data from the local machine to the server...correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What kind of hardware and software will your users be using?

Comment: @Peladao Windows desktop or laptop...what do you mean by software??

Comment: Web App... it will be easy to push out new version and fixes. Also, none of your objectives really help make the decision - they can all be done in both desktop and web app. What you want to consider is things like distribution, access, security and maintainability etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through those requirements, it sounds like this is more than one application.

Undoubtedly you need some sort of web application (probably ASP.NET in some form?) to allow the parents of students to asses their children's records.

However for security purposes this same application should probably not be used for teachers and administrative staff to edit these records. Those functions should be on a protected LAN, and require more application security for viewing or editing any potentially sensitive data (especially financial records).

I don't see where WCF would fit into this, unless you need to provide some web service support to some other system? Or perhaps proving some "application server" on a protected LAN that can use WCF to serve data to 2 separate applications for outside / public access (from separate web servers in a DMZ) and one for internal users.

There isn't really 1 answer to this question.

Comment: Suppose the school administration is using a desktop application to update the data...without using wcf how am i going to send the data to the server??The data has to be sent to the server in order to view it via website..hope am not confusing you.

Comment: That makes more sense. We do something similar at my current job. We have a WCF service running on a server in our LAN. Its job is to serve up data, and expose methods to edit data. Then we have a desktop app that talks to the central server with WCF, and a seperate ASP.NET website in the DMZ for external users that uses the same set of WCF services to edit the data. That allows you to centralize your business logic and security in that central WCF server.

Comment: Okay...so you are saying that i should have two wcf services ...one on the lan for the business logic and the other for communicating with the server.??

Comment: What if i have only one wcf service doing both the jobs-business logic and communication...??

Comment: I would assume the main server would house a WCF service, and the other (user interfacing) applications would talk to it using a WCF client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.Gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

You said "I am struggling whether I should develop for [desktop app + wcf] or web app(website)", but it sounds like you need to develop the [desktop app + wcf] anyway because the school administration is already using some sort of desktop application to update the data. You also need a web application for the parents to view their children's record.  If you can, I strongly suggest you skip the wcf and just do a web application.  At my current job, there's something similar to what rally25rs describe, and it is a pain in the ass to maintain the desktop application, the asp.net website and the wcf service business logic.  But it sounds like you have no choice, so good luck!